# A bit confused on how to respond to rail 3's remote link_to's…

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, response

I use rails `remote => true` on form's all the time. In jquery I use the `'ajax:before'` and `'ajax:success'` to pick up the events on the page and in the controller I do the following to respond to ajax or html calls:

```
format.html{
    redirect_to xxxx_path
}
format.json { 
    render :json => { :something => true }
}
```

However I seem to be having a lot of problems with putting remote true on links.

When I put remote true on a link, in the controller to respond to it if I do formal.json (below) nothing get's triggered:

```
format.json { 
    render :json => { :something => true }
}
```

and if I do:

```
format.js{  }
```

…in the controller there's is a response in the jquery. However the `'ajax:success'` event is not called, only the `'ajax:complete'` is called, which is incorrect.

I was wondering how do I set up a remote link in rails 3 which I can both respond to in the controller differently if the link is remote or just a normal html call. So respond with json for remote links and html for normal ones. And how do I get the jquery to pick up the 'ajax:success' response. I'm a bit confused as to how it all works.

Thanks!

Comment: Along with the `format.js` do you have a `method.js.erb` view for it to trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you narrow your question provide the code?

In the above, 'ajax:before' should be 'ajax:beforeSend'.

In your controller you can test if the request is ajax or not with something like

```
if request.xhr?
  render nothing: true
else
  redirect_to @your_object
end
```

You should add the format to your remote link to ensure the controller know what to answer

```
:'data-type' => 'html'
```

Comment: I added :'data-type' => 'json' to the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the format json in the url probably.

e.g.

```
<%= link_to some_path(format: :json, remote: true) %>
```